# is there is any way that i can get a folder stats with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, stat

Is there any way that i can get a folder stats with **node js**?.
I want a function in `nodejs` that i can see the folder stats not a file state
i have tried this function

```
fs.stat(path,(error,state)=>{
        console.log(state)
})
```

but it seems like it just works for files not folders 
im working on server-side with node.js
my code in case you need it

```
let folders=fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname,'../movies/'));
folders.map((paths)=>{
    fs.stat(paths,(f,state)=>{
        console.log(f,state)
    })

})
```

files in the above code have only folders
state is undefined
and thats what i get an error

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\DELL N5559\Desktop\stock\Folder'
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\DELL N5559\\Desktop\\stock\\Folder' }
    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Comment: What kind of 'stats' are you after? File Size, date created, author, etc...?

Comment: i need the folder date created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used properly, `fs.stat()` gives this information on a folder taken directly from a `console.log(stats)` in this code (as run on Windows, but I believe it should work on other platforms as well):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.stat("html", function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(stats);
    }
});
```

Result in console:

```
Stats {
  dev: 2525584580,
  mode: 16822,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: undefined,
  ino: 281474976939511,
  size: 0,
  blocks: undefined,
  atimeMs: 1517560386009.7627,
  mtimeMs: 1517560386009.7627,
  ctimeMs: 1517560386009.7627,
  birthtimeMs: 1517560385994.137,
  atime: 2018-02-02T08:33:06.010Z,
  mtime: 2018-02-02T08:33:06.010Z,
  ctime: 2018-02-02T08:33:06.010Z,
  birthtime: 2018-02-02T08:33:05.994Z 
}
```

Per [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_stat_time_values), the `birthtime` may or may not be the creation date (varies by OS).  `ctime` is not creation time (it's file node changed time, which is node parameters, not file content).

From the doc:

> birthtime "Birth Time" - Time of file creation. Set once when the file is created. On filesystems where birthtime is not available, this field may instead hold either the ctime or 1970-01-01T00:00Z (ie, unix epoch timestamp 0). This value may be greater than atime or mtime in this case. On Darwin and other FreeBSD variants, also set if the atime is explicitly set to an earlier value than the current birthtime using the utimes(2) system call.

Which seems like a way of saying, it's just a big mess and varies by platform.  So, if you wanted to use it for something useful, you'd probably have to test the heck out of your platform to see if it provided what you really need.

Related discussions:

[Get file created date in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552017/get-file-created-date-in-node)

[Is there still no Linux kernel interface to get file creation date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779/is-there-still-no-linux-kernel-interface-to-get-file-creation-date)

[How to get file created date using fs module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592299/how-to-get-file-created-date-using-fs-module/43592680)

---

In addition, in your code, you are not passing enough of a path to you `fs.stat()` function.  `fs.readdir()` returns just the file/dir name (no path attached) so when you then try to do:

```
folders.map((paths)=>{...}
```

The `paths` variable is just a single filename that is not in the current directory.  To make things work, you have to put the path back on it before calling `fs.stat()`.

```
let root = path.join(__dirname,'../movies/');
let folders = fs.readdirSync(root);
folders.map(name => {
    let fullname = path.join(root, name);
    fs.stat(fullname,(err, state) => {
        console.log(err, state)
    });
});
```

Comment: @GrinningTrout - Added another part of the problem where you weren't passing the full path to `fs.stat()` so it wasn't looking in the right path for your file/dir.

Comment: Notice that the size is zero, so this doesn't give the size of the folder contents, if that is what you are a looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The callback in `fs.stat` should be of the form `(err, stats) => {}`. You are printing out the error - so if there is no error, you won't get any output.

As a note, `fs.stat` will work for both files and directories as they are both more or less the same data structure in the underlying Node.js runtime.